# how to restore email from only a full website backup?

Tags: web-hosting, email, cpanel, backups

I am in a helpless position right now..Till last month,I was hosting my website and email accounts with hostgator and everything was going fine till I decided to switch hosting for some services that they dont currently offer.I cancelled my account with them and was given  a couple of hours to move my files.I created backup of the entire website from cPanel and downloaded everything from their server to my PC.The problem is,since this was a first time procedure for me,I didnt know that I had to download all my emails to my desktop client.I had read some tutorials providing information on moving my website to a new host and all ,but none of them mentioned about email backups.Now i have all my emails downloaded onto my desktop as part of the full website backup and not on any email client.And Hostgator has closed my account with them.The new host I have decided to move my website to,doesnt host email and they are asking me to host my emails on google apps.Thats ok with me,but I need all the emails in my account since all of them contain my registration and billing details and passwords  and other such important things.Please,can someone find me a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no good way to move the email from a cPanel backup into GMail. Ordinarily, you would either use a desktop client to download the messages and push them to GMail or have GMail fetch the email directly.

You can still get to the email, in a way, as they are stored as individual files within the backup. Not a perfect solution, but you could use a text editor to view the content, in a pinch.

Live and learn, I suppose.

Comment: Hi Justin...everything is fine now..i had referred many websites including the wordpress codex before i made the backup copies of my mails and the website..In wordpress codex itself,it was mentioned that if I was only moving my web host,i dont need to change anything..and it worked like it said..i moved my site to another cpanel host only..and everything is fine now..thanx for the help..bye